# How do I remove the last update to my Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios, xcode8

How do I remove the last update to my Xamarin ?
I keep getting this error 
Error MT0091: This version of Xamarin.iOS requires the iOS 11.0 SDK (shipped with Xcode 9). Either upgrade Xcode to get the required header files or set the managed linker behaviour to Link Framework SDKs Only (to try to avoid the new APIs). (MT0091)

but when I upgrade to Xcode 9, there where too many bugs...
so I need to just go back down.

Comment: check this link, download the version you want , but I think what you need is trying to solve the bugs instead of  downgrade the version